# Product price not update in cart Magento2

Tags: magento2, module, cart, shopping-cart

In my custom module, products are going to add directly to cart as below :

```
    foreach($productArray as $key => $id ) 
    {

    $p["qty"] = $qtyArray[$key]; 
    try {
                    $params = array(
                        'product' => $id,
                        'qty' => $p
                    );
                    $_product = $this->_productRepository->getById($id);
                    $this->cart->addProduct($_product,$params);
                    $this->cart->save();                            

        } catch(\Exception $e) { 
           $responseData['action']="errmessage";
            $responseData['msg'] = __("Something went wrong. please correct the sku(s)");
            $error = true;
        }
    }
```

A single product is added in the cart without issue but when we try to add multiple products together into the cart then the price of the first product is updated and subtotal is also updated but prices for 2nd individual products is showing 0
Any help will be appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: Above code is to add single product, please provide code that you used to add multiple products to cart.

Comment: Please check updated code

Answer (score 1):

After debugging, I have found the solution , `$this->cart->save();` must be after the loop.
Check below updated code:

```
 foreach($productArray as $key => $id ) 
    {

    $p["qty"] = $qtyArray[$key]; 
    try {
                    $params = array(
                        'product' => $id,
                        'qty' => $p
                    );
                    $_product = $this->_productRepository->getById($id);
                    $this->cart->addProduct($_product,$params);                                               

        } catch(\Exception $e) { 
           $responseData['action']="errmessage";
            $responseData['msg'] = __("Something went wrong. please correct the sku(s)");
            $error = true;
        }
    }
$this->cart->save();
```